# Authenticate Google Account with php

Tags: authentication, printing, cloud

Is there a possibility to log in on to Google Accountt with php? Until 26th of May I was using https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin to verify account. Now this method is disabled.

What Im trying to do is to connect Google Printer Cloud to print orders in resaturant. Client makes order on website then script sends auto genereted pdf to cloud which has connected printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've lost 2 days searching for solution with no success. I decided to change service and I've found https://www.printnode.com/ . Implementation their php library took me about 30 mins to work.